# CSS grid-template-columns not behaving the way I it to

Tags: css, html

I'm new to CSS grid and this is my first attempt.

In the code below there is an div container with the class grid-wrapper. It contains two sub divs with the class names grid-item. In the CSS they are referenced as grid-item:nth-child(1) and grid-item:nth-child(2). In the grid-wrapper the grid-template-areas place the grid-item:nth-child(1) and grid-item:nth-child(2) correctly.

The grid-item:nth-child(2) has children of it's own, but I can't them to line up correctly.

I do have a FSFiddle project.

Could someone enlighten me? Thanks in advance.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, {1fr});
    grid-template-areas:
      ". header header header header header header ."
      ". tabs tabs tabs tabs tabs tabs .";
}

.grid-item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #003566;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6a00;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: tabs;
  background-color: #b3cccc;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  /*grid-template-areas: "tabs tabs";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;*/
}

.logo {
    grid-area: logo;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color:#fff;
}

.logo span {
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #ff6a00;
}

.logo i {
    font-size: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fff;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(2)>div {
  /*grid-area: tabs;*/
  color: #003566;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>SurEyeDentity Host Services Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="logo">
        SurEyeDentity<span> Host<i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Services<i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Manager</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div>
        <i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Cameras
      </div>
      <div>
        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Users
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:grid` in the inner grid items...and use `grid-auto-flow: column` to align them column wise...use `justify-content: center` to align the items center horizontally..

And also you have used wrong value for the [**`grid-template-columns`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns)..As I see you don't need this so remove it

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, {
    1fr
  }
  );
  grid-template-areas : ". header header header header header header ." ". tabs tabs tabs tabs tabs tabs .";
}

.grid-item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #003566;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6a00;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: tabs;
  background-color: #b3cccc;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #fff;
}

.logo span {
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #ff6a00;
}

.logo i {
  font-size: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(2)>div {
  color: #003566;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>SurEyeDentity Host Services Manager</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="logo">
        SurEyeDentity<span> Host<i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Services<i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Manager</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div>
        <i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Cameras
      </div>
      <div>
        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Users
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That works! Thanks a bunch! I'll study it and get a complete understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Change .grid-item:nth-child(2)>div to .grid-item:nth-child(2) div

```css
body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, {1fr});
    grid-template-areas:
      ". header header header header header header ."
      ". tabs tabs tabs tabs tabs tabs .";
}

.grid-item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #003566;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6a00;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: tabs;
  background-color: #b3cccc;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  /*grid-template-areas: "tabs tabs";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;*/
}

.logo {
    grid-area: logo;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color:#fff;
}

.logo span {
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #ff6a00;
}

.logo i {
    font-size: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fff;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(2) div {
  /*grid-area: tabs;*/
  color: #003566;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>SurEyeDentity Host Services Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="logo">
        SurEyeDentity<span> Host<i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Services<i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Manager</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div>
        <i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Cameras
      </div>
      <div>
        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Users
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Changing .grid-item:nth-child(2)>div to .grid-item:nth-child(2) div didn't work, but the next answer below did. Thanks a bunch for the quick answer.